# fire dojo event from another function

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a button with an attached dojo event:

```
<span id="searchButton" title="Search" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: search"></span>
```

In a certain situation i want to fire this button/the dojo event from another function.
How could this function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dojo.byId('searchButton').click();
```